# How to add a regression line to line chart when i use data source as JSON - Highcharts.js react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, highcharts, linechart

im currently struggling to create a trend line to a line chart. found some old solutions and those things didn't work for me.

**Current code(Json file):**

```
[
{
    "key": "003",
    "title": "Detections",
    "type": "chart",
    "chartData": {
        "chart": {
            "type": "line",
            "renderTo": "container"
        },
        "title": {
            "text": ""
        },
        "subtitle": {
            "text": ""
        },
    
        
        
        "xAxis": {
            "categories": ["Jan 7", "Jan 14", "Jan 21", "Jan 28",
        "Feb 4","Feb 11","Feb 18","Feb 25",
        "Mar 4","Mar 11","Mar 18","Mar 28",
        "Apr 1","Apr 8","Apr 15","Apr 22","Apr 29",
        "May 6","May 13","May 20","May 27"
        
        
        ]
        },

        
        "colors": [ "#f89c1b"],

        "yAxis": {
            "title": {
                "text": "Number of Exits"
            }
        },
        "plotOptions": {
            "line": {
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "enableMouseTracking": false
            }
        },
        "series": [{
            "name": "Week",
            "data": [60,12,29,48,
            24,31,15,37,
            32,16,22,29,
            21,13,9,14,15,
            10,12,13,7]
        }
    ]
        

    },
    "index": 2,
    "defaultWidth": "100%"
}
]
```

Current chart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZXQn.png)

How do i add a regression line to this?

i found this link and it shows to add regression line in JS .But is there a way to do this using JSON ?

Comment: You can import the JSON file like: `import data from 'data.json'`. Then just use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to Javascript object: `const jsData = JSON.parse(data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar as for other indicators, you need to load and initialize proper modules (indicators and regressions in this case):

```
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import indicators from "highcharts/indicators/indicators";
import regressions from "highcharts/indicators/regressions";

indicators(Highcharts);
regressions(Highcharts);
```

And add new trendline series:

```
series: [
  {
    id: "mainSeries",
    name: "Week",
    data: [...]
  },
  {
    type: "linearRegression",
    linkedTo: "mainSeries"
  }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-fork-vjni21?file=/demo.jsx

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.linearregression

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek .but as on the live demo regression is not a line. Do you have any idea to convert it to a straight trend line?

Comment: Hi @Deric, This is how `linearRegression` works. Use `trendline` indicator to achieve the wanted result. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-03xc90?file=/demo.jsx